# plugin not working sencha touch

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to add new, month/year date pickerfield plugin, in a form.

[I found this plugin in one of sencha forums:](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?76187-datePicker-month-and-year-only)

Like it's written there, I added the two rows to my datepicker filed:

```
xtype:'datepickerfield',
name:'expDate',
label:'Expiration',
format: 'm-Y', // or other format you'd like
plugins: 'monthPickerPlugin',
picker:{ yearFrom:2012, yearTo:2030, slotOrder:['day','month','year']}
},
```

and I got the following error:
undefined is not an object

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: This is a plugin for 3.x

Comment: I'm Using Sencha-touch 1.1.0
What do you mean?

Comment: @kirilloid is saying that this plugin is for ExtJs 3.x and is not for Sencha Touch.

Comment: Thanks.
Do any of you Know how to implement this problem?
month/year datepicker xtype?

Comment: Actually I meant, this plugin is for 3.x and I thought, you use modern 4th version. Sencha touch may also be incompatible with plugin (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/ghuntley/Ext.ux.touch.DateTimePicker

I never tested it though